# Update partition schema name

Tags: postgresql

Any recommendation on the best way to change the partition schema location in PostgresSQL. The statement to change is
alter table tablename Set schema schemaname

Is there any pre work before running the schema change script

Thanks

Comment: Before anyone asks "why this downvote?", it's because of: This question does not show any research effort;

Comment: It takes a ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock, so it might interfere with concurrent processes. Just test and see for yourself.

Comment: So I tried and the statement runs successfully. It changed the schema name.  I ran some test and performance looks good. However before changing all their other partition schema name,  posted this question to see any pre-step recommendation.

Comment: Why do you think the schema name would have any impact on performance? It's just a namespace.

Comment: No reason and it really shouldn’t. The question was more related to recommendation steps, if any, prior running the schema change script. One step I performed was to detach the partition and attached it back after changing the schema. Looks like that was pretty much it. Thanks for posting the comments.